# Can't seem to be able to get new orders to start

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I completed bloodlines and rejected horkon but new orders won't start at all. I tried everything. I tried restarting the story.

Comment: You tried “everything”? Like what? Did you try talking to Isran?

Comment: How are you trying to start "new order"?

Answer (score 3):

When you rejected Harkon, he teleports you outside the castle gates. Your next move is to head back to Fort Dawnguard and speak to Isran. (Sometimes it won't let you fast travel back to the Fort. You will have to walk to Dayspring Canyon.)